# Make a portion of rectangle transparent in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Consider the blue area as the background/base layer. I want a center circle portion alone as transparent.

[image]

To put it in the coding perspective, I have graphical image as the background layer. This is in a rectangular shape. I want this to be rounded, so I'm trying to place an rectangle and ellipse to make the round area as transparent such that output is like below.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Part_Container"/>
```

[image]

The graphical image is done in the code behind within the ContentControl and so I won't be able to access that UI element. So I'm trying to place an ellipse or something on top of the content control to achieve it.

Comment: See `Xor` option in [How to: Create a Combined Geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-combined-geometry).